# VBA String Comparison with a return carriage

Tags: excel, string, vba, comparison, carriage-return

I am trying to compare 2 strings to find a match.
The code opens many files and for each file it fetches 2 strings that 
supposedly match to the ones I defined. 
However, one of the strings in a cell contains a carriage return and this is 
the reason why I can't seem to get a match.
Your help will be truly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

The related parts of my code for the comparison are the following:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim a, WScount, rows, j As Integer
Dim temp As String
Dim check1, check2 As Boolean
Dim str1, str2 As String

i = 1
j = 1

str1 = "Manufacturers Number"
str2 = "Manufacturers" & vbCrLf & " Number"

For Each WS In Worksheets
    N = 0
    rows = 1
    While N < 7
        temp = src.ActiveSheet.Cells(rows, 2)
        check1 = StrComp(str1, temp, vbTextCompare)
        check2 = StrComp(str2, temp, vbTextCompare)
        If check1 = 0 Or check2 = 0 Then
            For k = rows + 1 To 100
                temp = Cells(k, 2)
                If Not StrComp("", temp, vbTextCompare) = False Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, 3) = temp
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            Next k
        End If
            rows = rows + 1
            N = N + 1
    Wend

Next WS
```

Comment: For your given snippet you can try to replace the carriage return with an empty string like `Dim strCutted As String = Replace(str2, vbCrLf, "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vbCrLf` is equal to `asc` 10 and 13. E.g. "new line" and "carriage return" . [Ascii Table](https://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php).

Thus, you could simply these two values and give it a try:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim str1    As String
    Dim str2    As String

    str1 = "Manufacturers Number"
    str2 = "Manufacturers" & vbCrLf & " Number"

    str1 = stripTheString(str1)
    str2 = stripTheString(str2)

    Debug.Print str1 = str2

End Sub

Public Function stripTheString(strToStrip As String) As String

    Dim cnt     As Long
    Dim ascVal  As Long
    Dim newStr  As String

    For cnt = 1 To Len(strToStrip)
        ascVal = Asc(Mid(strToStrip, cnt, 1))
        If Not (ascVal = 10 Or ascVal = 13) Then
            newStr = newStr & Mid(strToStrip, cnt, 1)
        End If
    Next cnt

    stripTheString = newStr

End Function
```

The `stripTheString` function checks for `new line` or `carriage return` and removes them from the code. The code above could be a bit problematic, if you have new line without carriage return after it, as far as it will erase the new line in the `stripTheString` function.